# Silence unique constraint errors in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, csv, stderr

I'm loading CSV to sqlite db like this:

```
sqlite3 /path/to/output.db < /path/to/sqlite_commands.sql
```

The sqlite command file looks like this:

```
sqlite_commands.sql

CREATE TABLE products (
"c1" TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
"c2" TEXT,
"c3" TEXT
);
.mode csv

.import /tmp/csv_with_dups.csv products
```

and the csv looks like

/tmp/csv_with_dups.csv

```
c1,c2,c3
a,b,c
b,c,d
c,d,e
d,e,f
a,a,b
e,f,g
```

I am getting errors to stderr

```
/tmp/csv_with_dups.csv.tmp:6: INSERT failed: UNIQUE constraint failed: products.c1
```

I want to silence this error as we know that some csv have duplicates (the csv is generated by seperate mechanism on very large data set can can not validate duplicates at that stage)

I've tried adding this line per the documentation

```
.log off 

also tried
.log stderr|off

also tried 
.log stderr off

sqlite3
.help
...
.log FILE|off          Turn logging on or off.  FILE can be stderr/stdout
...
```

Comment: What should happen with the duplicates?

Comment: The behavior of duplicate handling is great (that is the one of the reasons we are importing the data to sqlite). I just don't want the errors to be reported to stderr. its blowing our logs up to massive size ( we know of the issue of duplicates in the CSV - just don't want to redirect all output, rather just stderr of duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

The "INSERT failed" message is always printed to stderr.

You could ignore stderr, but that would also suppress all other error messages:

```
sqlite3 ... 2>/dev/null
```

Alternatively, generate the SQL commands yourself so that you can use INSERT OR IGNORE:

```py
import sys
import csv

def quote_sql_str(s):
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "''") + "'"

print('BEGIN;')
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        print('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO products VALUES({});'
              .format(','.join([quote_sql_str(s) for s in row])))
print('COMMIT;')
```

```
python script.py csv_with_dups.csv | sqlite3 /path/to/output.db
```

Alternatively, import into a temporary table without constraints, then copy into the real table with INSERT OR IGNORE.

Comment: will that severely slow down compared to .import data.csv ?

Comment: That depends. What do your measurements show for your data on your machine?

Comment: we are importing 10M+ lines so it can take a good few minutes using the .import way. The reason I thought to do it using .import was that I was under the impression that it is the fastest and safest way, since creating my own CSV parser could be very difficult and parsing is time consuming. Just splitting by "," would fail 100% of the time in these CSV files.

Comment: Then use a better CSV parsing library …

Comment: Why shouldn't I be able to use the builtin functionality of sqlite for importing csv? that is a very strange suggestion

Comment: The `sqlite3` command-line shell always uses plain INSERTs. If you want to ignore constraint errors, you have to use something else.

Comment: Redirecting stderr doesn't have to absolute. You can filter stderr to suppress only those errors that you want to suppress, but still display all other errors.